# Sum duplicate on NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `NSMutableArray` with objects of type `NSMutableDictionary`,

the `NSMutableDictionary` contains 2 keys

-Airlines (string)

-Rating (integer)

I have an `NSMutableArray` with all the objects and what i need is to Sum the rating of all the airline companies repeated objects, an example:

```
Airline  Rating

  A         2

  B         3

  B         4

  C         5
```

The end result array will be the A = 2, C = 5 and the Sum of B´s that is equal to 7.

My code so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayMealRating.count; ++i) {
         NSMutableDictionary *item = [arrayMealRating objectAtIndex:i];
         NSLog(@"item=%@",item);
         for (int j = i+1; j < arrayMealRating.count; ++j)
         {
           if ([[item valueForKey:@"Airline"] isEqualToString:[arrayMealRating objectAtIndex:j]]){
                NSMutableDictionary *item = [arrayMealRating objectAtIndex:j];
                NSMutableDictionary *item1 = [arrayMealRating objectAtIndex:i];
                NSInteger auxCount =  [[item valueForKey:@"setMealRating"] integerValue] + [[item1 valueForKey:@"setMealRating"] integerValue];

                NSMutableDictionary *aux = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[item valueForKey:@"Airline"], @"Airline"
                                                        ,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",auxCount], @"setMealRating"
                                                        ,nil];
                NSLog(@"aux=%@",aux);
                [arrayMealRating replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:aux];

            }
         }
   }
```

A bit messy i know but i dont know how to work with `NSMutableDictionary`, any help will be much appreciated, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: could you post how its log is??? your explanation is little confusing..so it would be better, if we can see the log of your "arrayMeatRating" array log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incase you dont want to change how your storing the data, heres how you would do it using [key-value coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001838-SW1). Heres the dirrect link to the documentation for [@distinctUnionOfObjects and @sum](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-178593).

```
// Get all the airline names with no duplicates using the KVC @distinctUnionOfObjects collection operator
NSArray *airlineNames = [arrayMealRating valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.Airline"];

// Loop through all the airlines
for (NSString *airline in airlineNames) {

    // Get an array of all the dictionaries for the current airline
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Airline == %@)", airline];
    NSArray *airlineMealRating = [arrayMealRating filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    // Get the sum of all the ratings using KVC @sum collection operator
    NSNumber *rating = [airlineMealRating valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.Rating"];
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", airline, rating);
}
```

This gives the following output

```
A: 2
B: 7
C: 5
```

Comment: +1 wasn't aware of that. Very nice! (If it's working ;)) I guess I would do the redesign anyway though, but nevertheless this is great.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to redesign that entirely if that's at all possible.

Create a class `Airline`

```
@interface Airline : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *mealRatings;

- (void)addMealRating:(float)rating;
- (float)sumOfMealRatings;

@end


@implementation

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)pName
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.name = pName;
        self.mealRatings = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addMealRating:(float)rating
{
    [self.mealRatings addObject:@(rating)];
}

- (float)sumOfRatings
{
    float sum = 0;
    for (NSNumber *rating in self.mealRatings)
    {
        sum += [rating floatValue];
    }
 }

 @end
```

Then in your 'mainclass' you simply hold an `NSArray` with instances of your `Airline` objects. It might require you to change some of your existing code, but I think in the long run it saves you time and trouble. Perhaps you recognize later on, that you want to add additional properties to your Airlines. A dictionary is a cumbersome way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

@try this

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2] forKey:@"A"];
[myArray addObject:dict];

NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict2 setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:3] forKey:@"B"];
[myArray addObject:dict2];

NSMutableDictionary *dict3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict3 setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:4] forKey:@"B"];
[myArray addObject:dict3];

NSMutableDictionary *dict4 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict4 setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:5] forKey:@"D"];
[myArray addObject:dict4];


NSMutableDictionary *resultDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for(NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in myArray)
{
    NSString *key = [[dictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSInteger previousValue = [[resultDictionary objectForKey:key] integerValue];


        NSInteger value = [[dictionary objectForKey:key] integerValue];

        previousValue += value;



    [resultDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:previousValue] forKey:key];

}

for(NSString *key in resultDictionary)
{
    NSLog(@"value for key = %@ = %d",key, [[resultDictionary valueForKey:key] integerValue]);
}
```